# How to set ylim of only left axis object?

Tags: matlab

I use to `yyaxis` to create chart with two y-axes. Now I want to change ONLY the `YLim` of **left** axis to be zero.

I tried to use:

```
ax = gca;
ax.YAxis(1).YLim(1) = 0;
```

But I got an error message:

```
Assignment not supported because the result of method 'YLim' is a temporary value.
```

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yyaxis.html#d123e1592582):

> `yyaxis left` activates the side of the current axes associated with the left y-axis. Subsequent graphics commands target the left side.

So, use

```
yyaxis left
ax = gca;
ax.YLim(1) = 0;
```